# Lost my wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, reinstall

I am Somakumaran, I lost my WordPress Dashboard in bitnami AWS console.
can I recover through the lightsail terminal ? or can I re install the bitnami wordpress new?
if yes please get the commands for this pleas.

Comment: This sounds like an AWS issue, not an Ubuntu issue 

Comment: Your question is about AWS Lightsail with a product packaged and supported by Bitnami. Not on topic here